# R move files to folder based on list or column

Tags: r, file, directory, tidyverse

I have a large number of files (~25000) and want to move selected files to a specific directory after filtering the filename list.
The file name after filtering the list looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(filename = c("c2a1de2e-6451-4c95-8ce6-263f2b7e6eff", "67fa3e41-c7c6-44c5-9e67-6bcb2715aacc", "e21e2af3-dc71-41fa-94ba-7a7929f47d90", "5fd0f07b-8bb9-4378-bd26-28a26057e8fe", "4036c6fc-c82e-47bb-a384-6f299dc30b52", "bab43415-d413-40be-a4c0-2c40a52afe6a"))
```

How can I move the above files to a specific directory efficiently?

I tried to put list into:

```
setwd("local/dir/where/all/files/are/present)
dput(df)
filestocopy <- c("filenames from dput output")
targetdir <- ("Final/Final")
file.copy(from=filestocopy, to=targetdir, copy.mode = TRUE)
```

But since the file name is large and also the list is quite huge (like 25000 files) so moving 50-100 files at a time is taking huge time. I can not copy and paste dput output of more than 100 file name at a time.

Is there any efficient way to move file-based on matching name of data frame list?

Any input or suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why dput, maybe use df$filename?

Comment: @zx8754 It can be assigned to a variable but it gives numbered output so it wouldn't work. I am using because dput does not give numbered output but it is only for print purpose. I am trying to add some prefixes in the selected file names which are needed to move and then move files using prefix name and wildcard.

Comment: "gives numbered output" What do you mean?

Comment: @zx8754 because it is printing from a data frame. But honestly, I did not test your suggestion. I will give it a try tho somebody is already answered. Thanks dear for your time and help. I will try. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this should work:

```
# Set your input and target directories, and create the vector with the names of the files you want to copy (no need to make it a dataframe)
inputdir  <- "local/dir/where/all/files/are/present"  
targetdir <- "Final/Final"  
df <- c("c2a1de2e-6451-4c95-8ce6-263f2b7e6eff", "67fa3e41-c7c6-44c5-9e67-6bcb2715aacc", "e21e2af3-dc71-41fa-94ba-7a7929f47d90", "5fd0f07b-8bb9-4378-bd26-28a26057e8fe", "4036c6fc-c82e-47bb-a384-6f299dc30b52", "bab43415-d413-40be-a4c0-2c40a52afe6a")

# 1. List all the files in the folder
#    Note that you can also chose to list files with a specific pattern by adding an argument pattern = ".csv" for example.
filestocopy <- list.files(inputdir, full.names = TRUE)

# 2. Keep only the files that match the pattern you filtered 
filestocopy <- unique(grep(paste(df,collapse="|"), filestocopy, value=TRUE))

# 3. Copy the files
sapply(filestocopy, function(x) file.copy(from=x, to=targetdir, copy.mode = TRUE))
```

Comment: THank you for your help. Yes I want same thing but I waited and when no one replied so I just added prefix like "ABC" or "BCD" on filtered file and moved using filelist and wildcard like pattern = "ABC*" movetoTarget=/Final/ABC. Anywau Thank you so much for your help your answer is same which I wanted. Thanks